# Disable memory leak detectino of external library

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, memory-leaks

I am using VS2008 and trying to add memory leak detection to my project.
I added #define new DEBUG_NEW to all my .cpp files.

The problem is that I get thousands of leaks from an external library I am using.

How can I ignore memory leaks caused by external library?

The problem is that I can not do anything about them , nevertheless there are so many of them they obscure my real memory leaks caused by my application

Another question: I have many memory leaks regarding singletones. I create objects in their constructor that is never freed. so what can I do to overcome such memory leaks? (They too are not very interesting, but obscure real memory leaks)

Comment: What is your external library? If memory leaks are really caused by external library, why don't you change another library? Ignoring memory leaks is dangerous, especially 'run-time' leaks.

Comment: Its a licensing service. I use it once, and does not care about its memory leaks. Can not replace it